# Dynamically setting properties in the current context

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, codedom

What I am trying to achive is to dynamically set some properties at runtime in the current context of the app.

Eg:

Let's say I am running a web page and inside the page load event, I would like to dynamically set a property of a control - property which I have it stored in the db or external resource.

I've tried using reflection but it doesn't work as I should point to an existing object on compile time, not runtime.
Code example:

```
    string propertyName = "RadTabStrip1.Tabs[0]";
    string propertyValue = "Bla bla";

    Type t = typeof(RadTab);
    t.InvokeMember("Text", BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, propertyName, new object[] { propertyValue });
```

Is there a way to achieve this by using either reflection, codedome or LINQ expressions?

This would be fairly easy to achieve with CodeDom except that if I am using CodeDom it will execute outside the current context, which means I will not be able to access current context controls/objects. Is it possible to use some kind of `ref` parameters with codedom?

Answer (score 0):

From what i see you can simply use reflection f.e. like this

```
var tab = new RadTab(); // i guess you have that object reference somewhere else
var type = typeof(RadTab);
type.GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(tab, propertyValue);
```

Comment: In fact, RadTabStrip it's a Telerik control while RadTabStrip1.Tabs is an ICollection (List) and I need to dynamically set the first item's Text property in the list as such: RadTabStrip1.Tabs[0].Text = value;